# Rails Unable to import module IntelliJ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

I am new to IntelliJ. I am used to Visual Code.

After I setup everything and try to reload module so I can check debug environment.

But I am getting following error.

I tried to remove my gemset. Reinstalled rvm. But still I am getting this error. When I tried to click on Apply & OK.

[image]

Note: I am using Fish Shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it's correct or not.

After removing all the gems from global libraries, I am able to add module.

[image]